Little Boy Playing In His Room, Firetruck
First let me apologize for the lack of detail on this, but I was probably around 6 years old when I saw this movie. All I can remember is that the movie started out with a little boy around 6 or 7 years of age playing in his room, and there being a fire truck outside. I seem to recall the boy being transported into another world and meeting weird humonoid creatures (I think they were all short). The movie was live-action and could have been made anytime between 1980 and 1998. 

Welcome, druciferre.  How long ago did you see this?  Was the other world animated or live action?

Movie was live action, and I would have seen it in the mid 90's, but honestly, it could have been as old as 1980.

Do you remember why there was a fire truck outside?

I think of Time Bandits when reading your description. Only thing is that the fire truck is at the end of the movie and the boy is a little older.

+1 In spite of the lack of detail, I find it hard to believe that the description could fit any other movie. :)

+1 for having very little to go on, and it being somewhat inaccurate to begin with
